# Getting message from property file in Spring boot

Tags: spring, validation, resourcebundle, jsr

I am trying to read my error messages from a property file but I encounter this error message

```
org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'error.id.invalid' for locale 'en'.
```

I am using ResourceBundleMessageSource to set the base name

```
@Bean
public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:validations/messages.properties");
    return messageSource;
}
```

This is my exception Handler

```
@Autowired
private ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;

@ExceptionHandler(value = {ConstraintViolationException.class})
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ResponseBody
public ErrorMessageDTO handleResourceNotFoundException(ConstraintViolationException e) {

    ErrorMessageDTO message = null;

    if (e != null) {
        Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> violations = e.getConstraintViolations();
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (ConstraintViolation<?> violation : violations) {
            Locale currentLocale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
            String msg = messageSource.getMessage(violation.getMessage(), null, currentLocale);
            strBuilder.append(msg).append(", ");
        }
        message = new ErrorMessageDTO(MessageType.ERROR, strBuilder.toString(), BAD_REQUEST_ACTION, MODEL_INVALID_CODE);
        try {
            slf4jLogger.error(mapper.writeValueAsString(message));

        } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
            slf4jLogger.error(ex.getMessage());

        }
    }
    return message;
}
```

This is the directory structure of my project

```
src
   main
     resources
        validations
           messages_en_US.properties
```

Can someone please help me figure out what have I am I missing or have done wrong?

I know there are many questions related to this error but none of the solutions worked for me. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What if you remove the `.properties` and leave `messageSource.setBasename("classpath:validations/messages");` in the declaration?

Comment: That didnt help either @StanislavL

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to provide `ResourceBundleMessageSource`. Remove `.properties`

```
@Bean
public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:validations/messages");
    return messageSource;
}
```

Also try to provide a LocaleResolver as well.

```
@Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        return slr;
    }
```

Comment: That didnt help either. I also tried using `CookieLocaleResolver`

`public CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        Locale defaultLocale = new Locale("en");
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(defaultLocale);
        return localeResolver;
    }`